# How to make a new dataframe with original tweets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter

I am performing a sentiment analyses on tweets. I have made an algorithm that removes emoji's and some special characters before calculating the sentiment of the tweet. After that, the tweet without emoji's and special characters is put into a dataframe with the sentiments. Here is the code:

```
x = 0
a = 0
d = {}
for vertaling in df['text']:

    bericht = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', df['text'].iloc[x])
    bericht = re.sub(' +',' ', bericht)

    translations = translator.translate([bericht], dest='en')

    for translation in translations:
        a = a + 1
        print(a)
        print(translation.origin)
        analysis = TextBlob(translation.text)
        print(analysis.sentiment)
    x = x + 1
    d[translation.origin] = analysis.sentiment
c = ['Tweets','Sentiment']   
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=c)
```

I want the original tweet combined with the calculated sentiments. The code provided above combines the filtered tweets with the sentiment in this certain line:

`c = ['Tweets','Sentiment']

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=c)`

Does anyone know a way where I can combine the original tweet with the new calculated sentiment in a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the solution myself. Solution:

```
x = 0
a = 0
d = {}
#df2 = pd.DataFrame(['Tweets', 'Sentiment'])
df['Tweets'] = ""
df['Sentiment'] = ""
for vertaling in df['text']:

    df['Tweets'].iloc[x] = df['text'].iloc[x]

    bericht = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', df['text'].iloc[x])
    bericht = re.sub(' +',' ', bericht)

    translations = translator.translate([bericht], dest='en')

    for translation in translations:
        a = a + 1
        print(a)
        print(translation.origin)
        analysis = TextBlob(translation.text)
        df['Sentiment'].iloc[x] = analysis.sentiment

    x = x + 1
    d[translation.origin] = analysis.sentiment
```

This combines the new columns to my existing one.